# Create a popup with partialview data asp.net mvc5

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog, http-get, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have a panel containing a list of jobs with their ids and titles. 
Its just a simple view and a simple controller to go with it.

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.menuItem = "DashBoard";
        return View(db.jobs.ToList());

    }
```

items in a list:

```
 <li class="list-group-item"> @item.ID @item.Title</li>
```

I have created a details controller to display a partial view of that job:

```
 [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Details (int jobID)
    {

        var details = db.details.Find(jobID);
        return PartialView(details);
    }
```

and just a sandard view to go with it. using scaffolding.

How can i add an action link into that list that will display a pop up box when clicked with job details matching its ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By pop up box do you mean modal? If so then:

Change this part of your list

```
<li class="list-group-item"><a data-id="@item.ID" href="#">@item.Title</a></li>
```

I'm going to assume you're using jQuery and Bootstrap? If not I'll provide links below and check them out.

```
$('.list-group-item a').click(function (){
   //gets the id for the selected list item
   var itemId = $(this).data("id");

   //performs an ajax call to the controller to get the details based on the id selected
   $.ajax({
     url : 'your controller url',
     type : 'POST',
     data : {
       'jobID' : itemId
     },
     dataType:'json',
     success : function(data) {              
       //append the results to your modal's body.
       //$("modal selector").modal('show');
     },
     error : function(error)
     {
       //do something with the error
     }
  });
});
```

Links to [Bootstrap Modals](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) and [jQuery](https://jquery.com/)